# Query logic, wrong desired results mysql

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT * FROM 
MobileApps as dtable 
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) as c 
       FROM app_details
       WHERE trackId=dtable.SourceID)=0 
ORDER BY id ASC 
LIMIT 0,2
```

Problem is say the first two results ordered by id are in app_details, so the `COUNT(*)` doesnt' equal to 0 for the first two results. But there are much more results available in MobileApps table that would equal to 0.

I supposed it would first `SELECT * FROM app_details WHERE trackId=dtable.SourceID)=0` and then `ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 0,2`, not the other way around, what is a possible way to get it around ?

Thanks

Comment: It works correctly for me: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/536db/1

Comment: smells like a miscarried `... not exists ( SELECT ... ) ...` to me. Q: you want to get all from MobileApps where there are no app_details existing, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query works, but a better way to write it is:

```
SELECT dtable.*
FROM MobileApps dtable
LEFT JOIN app_details d ON d.trackId = dtable.SourceID
WHERE d.trackId IS NULL
ORDER BY dtable.id
LIMIT 0, 2
```

or:

```
SELECT *
From MobileApps dtable
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                  FROM app_details d
                  WHERE d.trackId = dtable.SourceID)
ORDER BY id
LIMIT 0, 2
```

See all 3 versions here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/536db/2

For a large table, you should probably benchmark them to see which one MySQL optimizes best.

Comment: I'd prefer the second alternative, more compact and clear, if that's OP's task.